# Quicksort not beginning sort process

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am (for homework, if that influences how the answers are given) supposed to be writing a class for quicksort to sort an array from a txt or dat file provided by the user.  I present the user with an menu option in the driver class to select sort type and then pass the array to the quicksort class for sorting, after which it is returned back to the driver class to be written to a file.  I believe the return is operating correctly, as I get the unsorted array printed to the file, however it only appears to be making one pass through the quicksort loop (determined by only one printing of the "Last Loop" string to the console.

The addition bits of code are part of the assignment, allowing a user to select Insertion sort to complete the sort if only 50 or 100 items remain in the unsorted array based on user choice.  I have tried running this program commenting those two if statements out and still the program does not correctly sort.  I am certain the input is read correctly as I have an addition HeapSort class that does sort correctly, and insertion sort returns correctly if that option is selected and the file size is less than 50 or 100 ints.  I cannot seem to get the QuickSort of a larger file to trigger though.

```
class Quicksort{
  int partition(int arr[], int lb, int ub){
     int i = lb, j = ub; 
     int temp; 
     int pivot = arr[0];
     while (i <= j) { 
        while (arr[i] < pivot){
           i++;
        }while(arr[j] > pivot){
           j--;
        }if (i <= j){
           temp = arr[i];
           arr[i] = arr[j];
           arr[j] = temp;
           i++;
           j--;
        } 
     }return i;
  } 

  int[] quicksort(int arr[], int lb, int ub, boolean insertLarge, boolean insertSmall){
     if (insertLarge && arr.length <= 100){
        System.out.println("Large");
        insertionSort(arr);
     }
     else if (insertSmall && arr.length <= 50){
        System.out.println("Small");
        insertionSort(arr);
     }
     else{
        int[] intArrCopy = new int[arr.length-1];
        for (int z = 1; z < intArrCopy.length; z++){
           intArrCopy[z-1] = arr[z];
        } 
        System.out.println("Last Loop");
        int index = partition(arr, lb, ub);
        if (lb < index-1){
           quicksort(intArrCopy, lb, index-1, insertLarge, insertSmall);
        }if (index < ub){
           quicksort(intArrCopy, index, ub, insertLarge, insertSmall);
        }
     }return arr;
  }

  public static void insertionSort(int x[]){
     int h, k, y;
     for (k=1; k < x.length; k++){
        y = x[k];
        for (h = k-1; h>=0 && y < x[h]; h--){
           x[h+1] = x[h];
        }x[h+1] = y;
     }
  }
}
```

And how it is being called from driver class:

```
private static void processChoice(int choice, int[] intArr){
  switch (choice){
     case 1:
        p = intArr.length;
        output = new int[p];
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        output = quick.quicksort(intArr, intArr[0], intArr[p-1], insertLarge, insertSmall);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time Taken: "+(endTime-startTime)+" nanoseconds.");
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: And how/where are you calling `processChoice`? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: I think you need to assign result of quicksort back to arr inside if/else - othetwise only tmpArr will be sorted.

Comment: I'll try that Jan.  Elliot, processChoice is being called from the main method, which I can edit it but it is somewhat ugly because I lazily handle all my input/output and checking input parameters there.  The debugger didn't work at first (I admit to probably not wielding it correctly) but now I see that it is jumping the while loop for "while i <= j" if i >j and not returning because of the conditions set in quicksort method

Comment: What's the purpose of this `intArrCopy` and why is it shorter than the original array? You don't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a hybrid sort, try something like this:

```
  void quicksort(int arr[], int lb, int ub){
     if ((ub-lb) < 100){             // < 32 may be fastest
        System.out.println("Large");
        insertionSort(arr, lb, ub);
        return;
     }
     int index = partition(arr, lb, ub);
     if (lb < index-1)
        quicksort(arr, lb, index-1);
     if (index < ub)
        quicksort(arr, index, ub);
  }

  public static void insertionSort(int x[], int lb, int ub){
     int h, k, y;
     for (h = lb+1; h <= ub; h++){
        y = x[h];
        for (k = h; k > lb && x[k-1] > y; k--)
           x[k] = x[k-1];
        x[k] = y;
     }
  }
```